# Arnold's problem #8

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The famous Arnold's problems (see 
http://www.math.upenn.edu/Arnold/Arnold-Trivium-1991.pdf ) are 
aimed at the strong graduate and postgraduate students of the top universities.
 I find it remarkable that a big part of the Arnold's problems can be solved with CASes.
However, I have not seen any satisfactory solution of his problem #8:

"How many maxima, minima, and saddle points does the function $ x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4 $
have on the surface $$  \{x+y+z+u+t=0,x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+t^2=1,x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+t^3=c\} ,$$ where $c$ is a real parameter?"
Can it be solved with Mathematica?

Comment: V.I. Arnold was a very gifted Mathematician and educator that believed in the geometrical perspective and intuition concerning tackling Mathematical problems. In his introduction on the above link he addresses the problem of the decreasing mathematical culture. I hope CAS's will not contribute further on that.

Comment: Using Lagrange multipliers, I'm getting a total of 70.

Comment: Could you present your results in MathematicaSE?

Answer (score 2):

I will give in this time...

Any Mathematical problem that a human has solved can also be solved using a CAS as a helper to save some time or waste some time...

`x,y,z,u,t` are real numbers and all the expressions above are of the form `x^k+y^k+z^k+u^k+t^k`.

One approach is to translate them using their symmetric polynomials `s1,s2,s3,s4,s5` where `si` the sum of all the possible products of `i` distinct terms from `{x,y,z,u,t}`

It is clear that `s1` is `x+y+z+u+t` which equals `0`

`SymmetricReduction[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + t^2, {x, y, z, u, t}, {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}]`

gives `s1^2 - 2 s2` and because `s1` equals `0` we get `-2s2` equals `1` so `s2` equals `-1/2`

`SymmetricReduction[
 x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + u^3 + t^3, {x, y, z, u, t}, {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}]`

gives `s1^3 - 3 s1 s2 + 3 s3` ==> `s3` equals `c/3`

and

`SymmetricReduction[
 x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + u^4 + t^4, {x, y, z, u, t}, {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}]`

gives `s1^4 - 4 s1^2 s2 + 2 s2^2 + 4 s1 s3 - 4 s4` which is equal to `1/2-4*s4`

Now let the equation `w^5 - s1*w^4 + s2*w^3 - s3*w^2 + s4*w - s5==0`

It is known that the roots are exactly `x,y,z,u,t` and of course w is real.

replacing `s1`,`s2`,`s3` in the above quintic :

`w^5 - s1*w^4 + s2*w^3 - s3*w^2 + s4*w - s5 /. {s1 -> 0, s2 -> -1/2, 
  s3 -> c/3}`

we get `-s5 + s4 w - s3 w^2 + s2 w^3 + w^5`

Solving for `s4`

`Apart@Solve[-s5 + s4 w - (c w^2)/3 - w^3/2 + w^5 == 0, s4]`

we get `s4` equals `s5/w + (c w)/3 + w^2/2 - w^4`

So the problem becomes : (Remember that `x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4` equals `1/2-4*s4`)

How many maxima, minima, and saddle points does the function `f[s5_,w_]:=1/2-4*(s5/w + (c w)/3 + w^2/2 - w^4);` has?

So now you have a 2-variable function that you can study very easily with `Dx,Dy,Dxx,Dyy,Dxy` theorem.

I think it is concave thought :-)

Comment: @ tchronis: Thank you for the interest to the question. You wrote "How many maxima, minima, and saddle points does the function f[s5_,w_]:=1/2-4*(s5/w + (c w)/3 + w^2/2 - w^4); have?" Could you explain that equivalence with the original problem  in detail? I don't understand that place.

Comment: Check you formatting again. Four spaces & no back ticks.

Comment: @user64494 after you find the characteristic points for `f` ,`w`,`s5` you substitute back to the preceding equations to find `x,y,z,u,t`

Comment: @Öskå you are right but I had to put many comments and thought that I didn't have a chunk of code to do that. Only lines of code. I will try to give a more algorithmic solution with a larger function that will contain them all...

Comment: @ tchronis: Why does a crtical point of   $ f[s5\_,w \_ ]:=1/2-4*(s5/w + (c w)/3 + w^2/2 - w^4);$  correspond to a critical point of $x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4 $?

Comment: @user64494 because `x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4` equals `1/2-4*s4`

Comment: @tchronis: Don't understand your point. The coordinates of critical points satisfy the necessary conditions which are expressed in terms of partial derivatives.

Comment: Big lines with four spaces & inline code with back ticks, easy :)